# flex how to reorder a list without refreshing its content?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

Here is a screenshot of my application.
This is a `<s:list>` component with an itemRenderer

When pressing up adn down buttons, the item should go down, up without refreshing the whole list (this is not drag&drop event, but simple click event)

My goal would be also to add a slide animation when an item goes down/up.

Any clues on how to achieve that effect ?

[image]

Comment: Just add the item at another index in the List's dataProvider.

Comment: what about effect ? How to create a move effect ?

Comment: I sure don't have an easy fix for that. The only thing I can think of, is to take a bitmap 'screenshot' of the affected rows, overlay them over the actual list and play the slide effect on those two bitmaps while the real List updates in the background.